# Mongodb stream call 'end' event too early

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm dumping mongodb to another mongodb using [stream](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/tutorials/streams/) on nodejs.

I have around 10 million docs per replica set. but stream call 'data' event only 1 million time or less then it call 'end' event. So I can not get documents equal to total docs ('data' event count is lower than stream.count by a lot).

Note that there is no 'data' event after 'end' event.

But sometime it works. It fetch all 10 million docs using the same code.

Is there any way I can debug this?

code here:

[main.js](https://gist.github.com/methuz/7ca8eaddc7b84c3cff08)
[mongoSync.js](https://gist.github.com/methuz/a4fa3924617679e56e5b)

Comment: Please post your code or a relevant part at least.

Comment: @ShanShan sorry I've just added it. Please check it out.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can call [`.count()`](https://gist.github.com/methuz/a4fa3924617679e56e5b#file-mongosync-js-L48) on the stream without exhausting the cursor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After dig into MongoDB module, I found that there is 'error' event which is not documented.

```
 stream.on('error', function(error) {
        console.error(error);
        db.close();
 });
```

Then I run it again, Wait until the error event happen then I found that there is a problem with network connection. Adding `timeout:false` to find function helps me on this case.

```
var stream = col.find(mongoSync.query, mongoSync.projection,{timeout:false}).batchSize(mongoSync.batchSize).stream();
```